# Local Notifications Plugin - Image/Logo

Tags: xamarin, notifications, xamarin.forms

I'm using Local Notifications Plugin for Xamarin, in a Xamarin Forms app.
(https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin) 
I got it working, but I have a question about the logo beside the notification.

I doesn't understand the readme on GitHub.

**Does anyone know how to change it?** 
(Both on Android and iOS).

[Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep5WK.png)

(I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links that's why I can't send pic on iOS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the icon you want to use to your Android project (under the Resources folder). Make sure the Build Action is set to `AndroidResource`, this should be done automatically.

Then somewhere in your Android project, probably the MainActivity is a good place, add this line: `LocalNotificationsImplementation.NotificationIconId = Resource.Drawable.YOUR_ICON_HERE`.

Of course at the place of the YOUR_ICON_HERE you should enter the identifier of your icon, which is probably the filename without its extension of the file you added.

Comment: Thank you so much Gerald!
It's working!
Do you have any tips for the iOS icon?@GeraldVersluis

Comment: Yes I will! :)  Do you have any ideas about the icon on iOS? @Gerald Versluis

Comment: AFAIK the icon on iOS is just the app icon, nothing you can do about that!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get the following error:

The name 'LocalNotificationsImplementation' does not exist in the current context

Comment: this is because you need to include the package by typing using Plugin.LocalNotifications;(and of course you need to install the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Notifier/)

Answer (score 0):

The Following are the steps to follow to change the icon in a flutter local Notification.

[image]

1. Resize the image you want to put to 72 x 72
2. Transfer the image into the Android-app-src-main-res- drawable folder.

   [image]
3. Change the default icon of the Application in the AndroidManifest file to that you put in the drawable folder

   [image]
4. Rerun the application and test the Flutter Local Notification and see if the changes appear.

Here are the results

[image]